# Flex - Content align to the bottom

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I make this layout with flex?
The left column has text with dynamic height

The right column has 2 parts... the text that is align to the top and the text that is align to the bottom. Is it possible with flex?

```
------------------------------------------
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   | XX Align To Top XX |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   |                    |
| Dynamic Height    |       Empty        |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   |                    |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   |  Align to bottom   |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps https://flexboxcssgrid.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent,
.child {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, totam! Voluptatum, necessitatibus. Reiciendis m ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, totam! Voluptatum, necessitatibus. Reiciendis m ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, totam! Voluptatum, necessitatibus. Reiciendis m ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, totam! Voluptatum, necessitatibus. Reiciendis quia nisi, quos vero architecto amet, incidunt sint tempore fugit, nulla in, saepe perspiciatis eos eius odit!</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: with bootstrap 4.1?

Answer (score 2):

i have done what you are looking for

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left content <br> left content <br> left content <br> left content</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">
      top content
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      bottom content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achive.

You will need to play with the `flex containers`. In this case, i used a `main` flex container. And the right flex item i turn it into anothe flex container to achive what you are looking for.

Hope this helps :>

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col{
  width: 50vw;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.col2 {
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.col2 div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="col col1">

  </div>
  <div class="col col2">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have 2 blocks as a parent and in the second block you will
   have 3 blocks.
2. On the parent block you need use `display: flex` to
   make your 2 parent blocks in row.
3. In the second parent block you need use also `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to make your inner 3 blocks column view. Also you need to add `justify-content: space-between` to divide your 3 blocks.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
}

.child__first,
.child__second {
  width: 50vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.child__first {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.child__second {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child__first">Child First</div>
  <div class="child__second">
    <div class="child__second-top">Child Second Top</div>
    <div class="child__second-middle">Child Second Middle</div>
    <div class="child__second-bottom">Child Second Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```